# one timer per thread using Qt

Tags: qt, qthread

I modified Qt's broadcast sender example so that it has ten threads and in each thread it starts a timer, but only timer of the first thread is triggered. How can I have one timer running for each thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple years later in OS course I learned: 
Timers are a **per process** thing. When a the OS kernel sends a timer trigger even whatever thread that is currently running gets the call and processes it. 
So I couldn't have ten timers per thread in a straight-forward manner.

Answer (score 1):

Timers only work if the thread has an event loop.